# Elasticsearch - Rolling up "other" results

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm trying to rollup some of my 'other' results using Elasticsearch. Ideally, I'd like my query to return the top N hits and then roll the rest of the data up into an N+1 hit titled "Other".

So for example, if I'm trying to aggregate "Institutions by Total Value", I'd get back 10 Institutions with the most value and then the total aggregated value of the other institutions as another record. The purpose is that I'd like to see the total value aggregated across all institutions but not have to list thousands.

An example search I've been using is:

```
GET my_index/institution/_search?pretty=true
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            ... terms queries ...
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "dimension_type_name_agg": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "institution_name",
        "order": {
          "metric_sum_total_value_agg": "desc"
        }, 
        "size": 0
      },
      "aggs": {
        "metric_sum_total_value_agg": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "total_value"
          }
        },
        "metric_count_account_id_agg": {
          "value_count": {
            "field": "institution_id"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm curious as to if this can be done by modifying a query like the one given above. Also, I'm using C# and Nest/Elasticsearch.NET so any tips on how this translates to that side is appreciated as well.